# Как добавить в модуль в Build Gradle?

Tags: android, настройка

[image: 1 что тут написано ? что подключено ?]
Не могу подключить новый модуль , при подключении нового модуля не билдится ... как всё исправить ...

Comment: Я думаю нашёл ответ, оказывается конфигурация compile теперь устарела и должна быть заменена implementation. И Спасибо, буду знать на счёт скриншот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это один из самых неожиданных изменений, произошедших с gradle: 3.0, который Google анонсировал на уровне IO17: 3.0

Конфигурация compile теперь устарела и должна быть заменена implementation или api.

Вы можете прочитать документы на странице
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

Comment: На самом деле все [немного сложнее](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations).